# Select equation in a list of conditions

Tags: list-manipulation

I have an equation list `{a'[t]==b[t],c'[t]==d[t],x'[t]==y[t]}` and upon running `FullSimplify[]` it becomes `{True,c'[t]==d[t],True}`. How to use e.g. `Select[]` to make a new list that contains only the non-trivial conditions (those are already `True`) -- in this case `c'[t]==d[t]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the answer: `Head[True]` is `Symbol` and `Head[a[t]==b]` is `Equal`. Therefore, `Select[{...}, Head[#] == Equal &]` does the job.